# Cannot get my stateful service to run. Pods can't get scheduled onto nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have been trying for a while to get a stateful service to start on my kubernetes cluster. 
The cluster has one master and one worker.  It's running on top of AWS EC2 instances running with Ubuntu 18.04.

I've tried everything that I can think of but when I create the stateful service, the pods won't get scheduled onto the nodes. 
I believe that it has something to do with the PV's, but I can't figure out what. 
Also, I'm having a hard time getting any diagnostics.  Trying to run kubectl logs on the pod and container returns nothing.

I first tried using local hardware, i.e. a local mount, but that didn't fix the problem. 
I've now created an AWS EBS volume and have created a PV that references this.
The PV binds to it correctly, but I still can't get kubernetes to schedule the pods on the worker node.

Here are the .yaml config files that I'm using.

The first one creates the storageclass called 'fast'

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Here is the yaml file that creates the PV.

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Finally, here's the statefulset yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  namespace: lab4a
  name: apache-http
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpd
  serviceName: "httpd-service"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: lab4a
      labels:
        app: httpd
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: httpd
        image: httpd:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: web-pvc
      namespace: lab4a
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
      storageClassName: "fast"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

kubectl get pv gives me:

```
NAME     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
ebs-pv   10Gi       RWX            Retain           Available                                   31m
```

So it stands to reason, at least as far as I can tell, that the PV is ready to go.
From my understanding, I don't need to supply a PV Claim manually as the volumeClaimTemplates section in the statefulset yaml file will do this dynamically.

kubectl get all -n lab4a gives me:

```
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/web-0   0/1     Pending   0          16m

NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/nginx   ClusterIP   None         <none>        80/TCP    16m

NAME                   READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/web   0/2     16m
```

when I run kubectl describe pod web-0 -n lab4a I get the following:

```
Name:               web-0
Namespace:          lab4a
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               <none>
Labels:             app=nginx
                    controller-revision-hash=web-b46f789c4
                    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=web-0
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:                 
Controlled By:      StatefulSet/web
Containers:
  nginx:
    Image:        k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
    Port:         80/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /usr/share/nginx/html from www (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-mjclk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  www:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  www-web-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-mjclk:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-mjclk
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  35s (x14 over 16m)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

I have no idea what's failing, and I don't know what else to try to debug this problem.  Is kubernetes failing to bind the persistent volume to the node? Or is it some other issue?

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Are there any events on the node's themselves?```k describe node x``` . Are you sure they are in the ready state and are reachable from the master plane? How did you provision the cluster? I don't see anything wrong with the definitions themselves which makes me think there's something up with the nodes, since the taint implies they are either not ready or unreachable.

Comment: I've gotten a bit further with this.  I've solved some issues, but I still can't get it to work. The problem now seems to be that the pvc cannot access the AWS cloud provider for some reason.  Is there something that I need to do ahead of time with kubeadm to make sure that it understands how to get to AWS for connecting to EBS instances?

Comment: `0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.` What is so hard about reading the output from the scheduler about why it refuses to schedule your pods? [The fine manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) will give you the gory details

Comment: Having changed a few things, I've gotten passed the issue of the taints.  The problem is simply now this:  No matter what I do, I cannot get the stateful set pods to bind to the PV. 
The error is:
 0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.

Even though I have the PV created and ready, nothing I can do seems to work to get the dynamic provisioning in the statefulset to actually bind.

Answer (score 1):

### (1) Your Storage

AWS EBS does not provide `ReadWriteMany` (see table in the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).

You can

- Use `ReadWriteOnce` instead (proposed).
- Set up an in-cluster NFS that hosts PVs that allow `ReadWriteMany` if you do have an actual need for this.

### (2) Your Taints and Tolerations

Your Pod's tolerations look okay; can you provide insight on your nodes' taints? Did you fiddle around with `kubectl taint ...` before on this cluster? Is this a managed cluster or did you set it up on your own on AWS machines?

Comment: I set it up on my own.  I've been fiddling around with this for a few days.  I went back to local storage for the PV.  The problem now is that it keeps saying that it can't find available persistent volumes to bind even though I have created the PV's.  I haven't done anything with kubectl taint at all.  Is there a way to debug this further?  I.e. is there somewhere that I can look at debug output to see why it can't find the PV?

Comment: Can you remove `provisioner` and `parameters` keys of your storage class? If PVs are already there, you don't need no provisioning and instead just want to "select" an appropriate PV by its storage class name. You could also go for direct name-based binding in the PVC.